# Multiple Intent receivers?

Tags: android, android-intent, action

Documentation states that if an `Intent` can be processed by multiple applications the user will be prompted with a dialog asking him to choose the application to complete the action. Is there any way to make user select multiple applications that will complete the action one by one? For example, if I want to share a message I'll be using `ACTION_SEND` with a specified MIME type and I'll be prompted with a list of applications that can share the message. Can I make a user choose multiple apps to share message on Twitter, Facebook etc. at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - you'd most likely have to use the Facebook, Twitter etc APIs and write your own mechanism to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to make user select multiple applications that will complete the action one by one?

Not native to Android.

That being said, there is nothing stopping you from using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to create your own chooser that allows multiple selection, then dispatches the event to each checked item one by one.

Comment: @Egor: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot -- that sample project demonstrates using the aforementioned APIs to implement an app launcher. In your case, you would make it multiple-choice and substitute in your own `Intent` instead of the one I am using, plus update the UI to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The way OS handles it, seems no.
You talk about [this](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html), right?
Because you load text, and/or image, and then sharing it.
Lot of apps can handle it, but every app handles it with different way.
May the app who when get text and/or img, do nothing!

e.g G+, asks you what circles you want to share with.
facebook i dont know, i dont use it.
SMS/MMS: may see if there is a picture or something to choose between them.

Even dropbox sometimes thinks can handle some sharings, but eventually it cant!

Also, there is no option for multiple select in sharing.

If there was, what was going to happen?
eg selected g+ and twitter, open first the G+ New post Activity,
and when you finish, open the Twitter one?

Maybe using API's for those soc. networks, but user may have to give again its credencials.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you got the question absolutely right.