# Implicit intent and multiple receivers?

Tags: android, android-intent

Android documentation tells us that an implicit intent might be received by multiple components (as all of them would have registered with the specific intent filter), and the system pops up a dialog asking which component to use to handle the intent.

However, I was wondering if this mechanism of popping the dialog, to asking which component should handle the intent, be over-ridden, s.t. 2 (or more) components get a chance to handle the intent ? A classic example for this, in my mind would be a "Cyber Nanny" type application, which gets the ACTION_VIEW type intent, checks the URI to be say "child safe", and then permit it to invoke the Browser. Similarly, for making / receiving calls from / to specific parties -- as in black-list or white-list of numbers. If the user sees the dialog, then they might circumvent the system, which is what I do not want. If the effect cannot be achieved using some mechanism around the Intents, is there an alternative way ?

**Edit:**
*After posting my question I found a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376561/multiple-intent-receivers), but it is not exactly same, because in my case, I am looking at ways to avoid that pop-up dialog. Hopefully, there's a method, that does not require rooting the device.*